# Python: What is the easiest way to test all the elements from a set that is changing dynamically?

Tags: python, loops, set

I have a set, and I need to test all the elements in it for a specific property. As part of this test, new elements might be discovered that also need to be tested. So I was thinking of writing the code like this:

```
thisset=FunctionThatReturnsASet()
for element in thisset:
    newelements=NewElementsBasedOnElement(element)
    thisset|=newelements
```

but would it work? Can I use the construct for in with a set that changes while I am working. And would the new elements also be tested before it exits the loop?

Comment: `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`

Comment: who populates the set with new elements, another thread?

Comment: no, the same thread. But I have solved thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot update a set while at the same time iterating over it.

Create a *copy* of the set, and use a `while` loop to remove elements as you loop. Add elements to that set to process. By using `while` you don't directly iterate over the set itself:

```
queue = thisset.copy()
while queue:
    element = queue.pop()
    # ...
    queue |= newelements
```

Note that this can mean you are processing elements more than once if you re-add them after processing. If this is an issue you'll need to track them separately in a `seen` set that you only add to:

```
queue = thisset.copy()
seen = set()
while queue:
    element = queue.pop()
    if element in seen: continue
    seen.add(element)
    # ...
    queue |= newelements
```

Comment: This might infinite loop if the test for `element` adds itself to the queue, or something else circular like that. You might want a queue and a visited set.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: I was already typing that up when a colleague here distracted me with some actual work. :-)

Comment: Thanks. An element will never find itself, but it is possible to find another element that was already tested. I can use a "seen" set but I wanted to avoid the extra cost of checking through it.